# VueJs: show a skeleton loader when the image is loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, vuejs3

I need to check if the image was loaded by the browser and if all data was fetched, then display a content, if not, show `<ItemCardSkeleton />` component instead. So if one image is loaded faster than the others, I would want to show the content, and rest would have a skeleton until they are fully loaded one by one.

My attempt: I check if the image was loaded with by adding `@load`, so if `isLoaded` is set to `true` it means it's loaded. Then I check if the data from API is pending (I passed a prop to the child component) and if the `isLoaded` is `true`, then display `<ItemCardSkeleton />`.

Problem: when I set the throttling to 2G and reload the page, the all of the loaders appear together at once in a few seconds and `<ItemCardSkeleton />` loads infinitely, so I never see the real cards appear. Also, I can see `{{ isLoaded }}` is always `false` in the template.

Parent component ItemSwiper.vue:

```
<template>
    <Swiper>
        <template v-for="recipe in storeRecipes.data" :key="recipe.id">
            <SwiperSlide class="swiper__slide">
                <ItemCard :data="recipe" :pending="storeRecipes.data" />
            </SwiperSlide>
            <div class="swiper-custom-pagination"></div>
        </template>
    </Swiper>
</template>

<script setup>
import { onMounted } from 'vue';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue';
import { useStoreRecipes } from '@/stores/recipes/storeRecipes.js';

import ItemCard from '@/components/ItemCard.vue';

const storeRecipes = useStoreRecipes();

onMounted(() => {
    storeRecipes.loadRecipes();
});
</script>
```

Child component ItemCard.vue:

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__item">
            <ItemCardSkeleton v-if="pending || !isLoaded" />
            <template v-else>
                <img
                    class="card__image"
                    @load="isLoaded = true"
                    :src="getSrc('.jpg')"
                    :alt="data.alt"
                    width="15.625rem" />
                <div class="card__content">
                    <h2 class="card__title">{{ data.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="card__text">{{ data.text }}</p>
                    <router-link class="card__link" :to="{ name: 'Home' }"
                        >View more</router-link
                    >
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import ItemCardSkeleton from '@/components/SkeletonLoaders/ItemCardSkeleton.vue';

const props = defineProps(['data', 'pending']);

const isLoaded = ref(false);

const getSrc = ext => {
    return new URL(
        `../assets/images/recipe/${props.data.image}${ext}`,
        import.meta.url
    ).href;
};
</script>
```

Comment: since the `<img` isn't even added to the DOM until `isLoading` is true and `pending` is false, `getSrc` will never be called, and therefore the image can never load

Comment: pending set to true here `code <ItemCardSkeleton v-if="pending || !isLoaded" />`, because it's waiting until the data is fetched.

Comment: sure, but while pending is true, the image can not begin to load of course ... so, how will the image begin loading?

Comment: that's why I used v-if on ItemCardSkeleton. Basically, when data is pending and when isLoaded is false, render ItemCardSkeleton. Else, load the img+card content.

Comment: but `isLoaded` has to also be true for `v-else` to be rendered - how is `isLoaded` set to true?

Comment: in the @load="isLoaded = true". Also, v-else basically means it's going to set the opposite value of !isLoaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255726/discussion-between-michael-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: but `@load="isLoaded = true"` can't trigger until the image is loaded, and the `<img` tag isn't even rendered until `isLoaded` is true ... so `@load="isLoaded = true"` can't run, until it has already run

Comment: you also seem to forget ... the skeleton is shown if `pending` is true/truthy **OR** `isLoaded` is false - I see nothing in your code that would change the value of `pending`

Comment: v-else should change the pending to false (I created a chat, so if you want we can continue there)

Comment: `v-else` won't change the value of pending at all. and besides, `v-else` won't render until `isLoaded` is true, but `isLoaded` is only set to true once `v-else` is rendered ... so how can `v-else` render while `isLoaded` is false? and no - I don't chat

Comment: because in global store I defined a 'pending'.  `code export const useStoreRecipes = defineStore('storeRecipes', {
state: () => {
return {
data: [],
pending: false,
};
},
actions: {
async loadRecipes() {
try {
this.pending = true;
const res = await fetch('/api/recipe');
if (res.ok) {
const data = await res.json();
this.data = data;
} else {
console.error('Error: ', res.status, res.statusText);
}
} catch (err) {
console.error(err);
} finally {
this.pending = false;`

Comment: BUT `isLoaded` also has to be true before the `v-else` block is rendered, so when will `v-else` be rendered? You seem to misunderstand that only one of, v-if/v-else blocks will actually render on the DOM, and therefore, the image can't even BEGIN loading until `v-if` is false (i.e. `pending == false` AND `!isLoaded == false` because that's the opposite of `pending || !isLoaded`) - and `@load` can't trigger until the image loads, which happens AFTER it begins loading, which it never does

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `isLoaded` has to be true for the `<img` to be rendered so that `isLoaded` can be set to `true`

So, clearly you have an impossible situation since `isLoaded` can't be set to true until it already IS true.

To illustrate what your code is doing, consider this:

```js
let isLoaded = false;
let pending = true;
function x(n=0) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({n, pending, isLoaded}));
    if (n > 9) return;
    if (pending || !isLoaded) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            pending = false;
            x(n+1);
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        isLoaded = true;
    }
}
x();
```

As you can see, `isLoaded` can only be set to true when `isLoaded` is already true (the code only runs for 10 seconds, `isLoaded` can never be true with this logic

Try the following

remove the `@load` from the `<img`

use `onMounted` to *pre*-load the image into a `new Image`

when the image loads, set `isLoaded = true`

Something like:

```
<template>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card__item">
            <ItemCardSkeleton v-if="pending || !isLoaded" />
            <template v-else>
                <img
                    class="card__image"
                    :src="getSrc('.jpg')"
                    :alt="data.alt"
                    width="15.625rem" />
                <div class="card__content">
                    <h2 class="card__title">{{ data.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="card__text">{{ data.text }}</p>
                    <router-link class="card__link" :to="{ name: 'Home' }"
                        >View more</router-link
                    >
                </div>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import ItemCardSkeleton from '@/components/SkeletonLoaders/ItemCardSkeleton.vue';

const props = defineProps(['data', 'pending']);

const isLoaded = ref(false);

const getSrc = ext => {
    return new URL(
        `../assets/images/recipe/${props.data.image}${ext}`,
        import.meta.url
    ).href;
};
onMounted(() => {
    const img = new Image;
    img.onload = () => isLoaded.value = true;
    img.src = getSrc('.jpg');
});
</script>
```

The only issue is, I can't see how `pending` becomes `false`, but that's up to you I guess

To demonstrate with the analogous code from above, some other code needs to set `isLoaded = true` (which is done when the `new Image` loads in the answer, but here in this demo, just in a timeout after 5 seconds)

```js
let isLoaded = false;
let pending = true;
function x(n=0) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify({n, pending, isLoaded}));
    if (n > 9) return;
    if (pending || !isLoaded) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            pending = false;
            x(n+1);
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        isLoaded = true;
    }
}
x();
setTimeout(() => {
    isLoaded = true;
}, 5000)
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! For now I will just remove 'pending' and focus on isLoaded. So I added
`code <ItemCardSkeleton v-if="!isLoaded" />` 
and 
`code onMounted(() => {
    const img = new Image(getSrc('.jpg'));
    img.onload = () => {
        isLoaded.value = true;
    };
});`

However, if I render {{ isLoading }} now, I can see the value is always 'false'. Also, the skeletons are loading infinitely.

Comment: try adding an `img.onerror` to debug - or check the developer tools to see if there's an error loading the image . I take it you remembered to add `onMounted` to the import from vue? I didn't put that in the answer because I forgot

Comment: I imported it. Console doesn't show errors.

Comment: OK, I made a mistake with `new Image` see updated code - I thought `new Image` took the src as an argument ... it doesn't :p

Comment: NOW it works! Thank you so much! Tbh I didn't even think about onMounted.

Comment: Actually, is there any point to also check if the data is pending, if the images are usually rendered slower than the text from API? So we can only check if the image was loaded. Or do you recommend checking both for safety?

Comment: You should do what you think is best :p

Comment: I understand, but from what I think, images usually load slower so we can just check only images. But what if something happens and the data is going to load too slow? I think for safety we should check both pending and the image loading status.

Comment: I probably would do the same, don't render until everything is ready to render

Answer (score 1):

You should change `:pending="storeRecipes.data"` to `:pending="storeRecipes.pending"` in `ItemSwiper.vue` if you intend to pass a boolean indicating whether the data is still loading. Additionally, initialize `isLoaded` as `false` for each new card component.

##### ItemSwiper.vue

```js
<template>
    <Swiper>
        <template v-for="recipe in storeRecipes.data" :key="recipe.id">
            <SwiperSlide class="swiper__slide">
                <!-- Pass the boolean flag indicating loading state -->
                <ItemCard :data="recipe" :pending="storeRecipes.pending" />
            </SwiperSlide>
        </template>
    </Swiper>
</template>
```

##### ItemCard.vue

```js
<template>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card__item">
      <ItemCardSkeleton v-if="pending || !isLoaded" />
      <template v-else>
        <img
          class="card__image"
          @load="isLoaded = true" <!-- This should set isLoaded to true when image loads -->
          :src="getSrc('.jpg')"
          :alt="data.alt"
          width="15.625rem" />
        <!-- ... -->
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import ItemCardSkeleton from '@/components/SkeletonLoaders/ItemCardSkeleton.vue';

const props = defineProps(['data', 'pending']);

// Initialize as false for each new component
const isLoaded = ref(false);

// ...
</script>
```

Make sure the `getSrc('.jpg')` is providing the correct path. If the path is incorrect or if there's any issue with the image loading, the `@load` event will not be triggered, and `isLoaded` will remain `false`.

With these changes, each card will independently control its own loading state, ensuring that the skeleton loader displays until both the data and the image are loaded for each card.

Comment: You're right! I put data instead of pending accidentally. Thank you.

Comment: a) you don't use `.value"` in a `v-if` and b) how will `isLoaded` ever become true?

Comment: Nice catch. Updated.

Comment: In global store, where I define 'pending', I have an action:
`code
async loadRecipes() {
  try {
 this.pending = true;
  const res = await fetch('/api/recipe');
  if (res.ok) {
  const data = await res.json();
  this.data = data;
 } else {
     console.error('Error: ', res.status, res.statusText);
   }
  }  catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
  } finally {
      this.pending = false;
     }
   },
`

So when the data is fetched, it should set the pending to false. However, if I set `code <ItemCardSkeleton v-if="pending" />` to check, I don't see the skeleton component.

Comment: There might be an issue with the reactivity of your pending state from the global store. Ensure that pending is a reactive state and that you are importing and using it correctly in the parent component.

Comment: I don't know what can be the issue, because I have an action that changes the state, depending if the data was fetched or not. I've read about storeToRefs as well, but it kind of does the same thing, just if we wouldn't have an action.